# Azure: How to change idle timeout for Resource Manager managed VMs/IPs

Tags: powershell, azure, tcp

I was surprised to find out that Azure enforces a slient TCP connection timeout, which is by default set to 4 mintues. I need to change this, as we're running long-running TCP connections and no communication should be sent to conserve power on embedded devices.

There are a couple of guides online (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-configurable-idle-timeout-for-azure-load-balancer/), but they all cover cases where the VMs are provisioned using the Service manager (Classic). So changing this in Classic is not an issue, but we're already running the VMs provisioned via the Resource Manager.

After running:

```
Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager
Get-AzureVM -Name "MyVM" -ResourceGroup "MyGroup" | Get-AzurePublicIpAddress
```

I get the configuration printout for the IP, with `IdleTimeoutInMinutes` set at default `4`.

Changing this using:

```
Get-AzureVM -Name "MyVM" -ResourceGroup "MyGroup" | Get-AzurePublicIpAddress | Set-AzurePublicIpAddress -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 29
```

fails with: `` A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name `IdleTimeoutInMinutes` ``.

A guide or suggestion how to go forward will be appreciated. Should I remove the IP and create a new one? There surely is a better way.

Comment: check this out https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/02367d11-0960-4081-847b-294eb01ec4db/azure-powershell-idletimeoutinminutes-value-for-vm-not-updated?forum=azurescripting

Comment: @BrijRajSingh not sure how that link helps, it references the "Classic" approach. Is it a problem of me using Dynamically allocated IPs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for the 1.x cmdlets:

```
$p = Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name MyIP -ResourceGroupName MyGroup
$p.IdleTimeoutInMinutes = 29
Set-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -PublicIpAddress $p
```

Or if you're on the older 0.9.x cmdlets:

```
Switch-AzureMode
$p = Get-AzurePublicIpAddress -Name MyIP -ResourceGroupName MyGroup
$p.IdleTimeoutInMinutes = 29
Set-AzurePublicIpAddress -PublicIpAddress $p
```

Comment: Sorry, ```Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress``` is not available in my version of Azure Powershell.

Comment: You'll want to upgrade to the "GA" version of the new AzureRM cmdlets: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/ - note there are new cmdlets names (as you have noticed) and that will affect any existing scripts...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the new AzureRM cmdlets. I had the correct version of Azure installed, but I did not reboot the computer after installation. After the reboot the AzureRM cmdlets are available and after following the Getting Started guide on: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azps-1-0/ all is well. 

Thank you @bmoore-msft!

Comment: Ugh... sorry about that.  Yes, there is a "bug" in PowerShell where it doesn't always update the psmodule path after installing a new module.  A reboot (or log off + log on) fixes that.